# Set Mark on articles that have process marks

Tags: gnus

How can I [set a “mark”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Setting-Marks.html) (for example, mark as read) all the **articles that currently have “process marks”**?

This is confusing to talk about since there are two very distinct “mark” concepts in Gnus.

As an example,: I use `gnus-uu-mark-by-regexp` to [set “process mark”s](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Setting-Process-Marks.html) to an arbitrary subset of articles. Now I want to mark only those articles as read.

Something like `gnus-summary-mark-as-read-forward` apparently ignores the “process mark” and apparently only cares about the article at point.

What can I use to get the commands described in [Setting Marks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Setting-Marks.html), but apply them specifically to those articles with “process mark” already set?

Comment: If you think that's confusing, that's not even the normal meaning of "process mark".  (See `M-x elisp-index-search RET process-mark`).